# How to Divide React Components into Presentational and Container Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, components, mern

Still new to react and redux and have been working on a MERN user registration application which I got working now.

In the redux documentation I found the creators recommend splitting their code up into two types of components when integrating redux with react: Presentational (concerns with how things look) and Container (concerns with how things work). See https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact.

I think this would allow for better management and scalability of the application.

For people unfamiliar, here is a good explanation of the advantages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NazjKgJp7sQ

I only struggle in grasping the concept and rewriting the code in such a way.

Here is an example of a post component I written using to display user created comments. It is receiving the data from the post in a higher-level component passed down as props. In the return I have all my markup with bootstrap styling applied. I am subscribing to redux actions I imported and using by creating event handlers.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { deletePost, addLike, removeLike } from '../../actions/postActions';

class PostItem extends Component {
  onDeleteClick(id) {
    this.props.deletePost(id);
  }

  onLikeClick(id) {
    this.props.addLike(id);
  }

  onUnlikeClick(id) {
    this.props.removeLike(id);
  }

  findUserLike(likes) {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if (likes.filter(like => like.user === auth.user.id).length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { post, auth, showActions } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="card card-body mb-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <a href="profile.html">
              <img
                className="rounded-circle d-none d-md-block"
                src={post.avatar}
                alt=""
              />
            </a>
            <br />
            <p className="text-center">{post.name}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-10">
            <p className="lead">{post.text}</p>
            {showActions ? (
              <span>
                <button
                  onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, post._id)}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                >
                  <i
                    className={classnames('fas fa-thumbs-up', {
                      'text-info': this.findUserLike(post.likes)
                    })}
                  />
                  <span className="badge badge-light">{post.likes.length}</span>
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={this.onUnlikeClick.bind(this, post._id)}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                >
                  <i className="text-secondary fas fa-thumbs-down" />
                </button>
                <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="btn btn-info mr-1">
                  Comments
                </Link>
                {post.user === auth.user.id ? (
                  <button
                    onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, post._id)}
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-danger mr-1"
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-times" />
                  </button>
                ) : null}
              </span>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PostItem.defaultProps = {
  showActions: true,
};

PostItem.propTypes = {
  deletePost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deletePost, addLike, removeLike })(PostItem);
```

As you can see is the code not as neat and compact as I would like. My goal is to make the presentational component unaware of redux, and do all styling and bootstrap stuff here, while the container component have the redux and connect functionalities. Does anyone know how I should approach this?

I saw people using connect to link these types components together:

```
const PostItemContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    { deletePost, addLike, removeLike }
)(PostItem);

export default PostItemContainer;
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this in practice.
If you could help me explain and provide some example code that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jsDevia's answer is a good one, though I wouldn't use an arrow function for `onClick` for small apps, I think this is not a problem for small ones. I wonder something, is your `Post` component connected to Redux?

Comment: Yes, my Post component is also connected to redux.

Are you suggesting only the highest level component should be connected to redux?

Comment: If this component can be a container component for all other presentational ones, yes I can suggest that. @jsDevia's answer is similar to this logic but he uses another component for that. But, you have already a `Post` component and it is connected to Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always put my html like ( presentation ) code in another file, which in react they call stateless component,

The key component is PostItemComponent which does not know anything about redux.

see the code below :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { deletePost, addLike, removeLike } from '../../actions/postActions';

const PostItemComponent = ({
    post,
    showActions,
    auth,
    onLikeClick,
    findUserLike,
    onUnlikeClick,
    onDeleteClick
}) => {
    return (
        <div className="card card-body mb-3">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <a href="profile.html">
                        <img
                            className="rounded-circle d-none d-md-block"
                            src={post.avatar}
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </a>
                    <br />
                    <p className="text-center">{post.name}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-10">
                    <p className="lead">{post.text}</p>
                    {showActions ? (
                        <span>
                            <button
                                onClick={(event) => onLikeClick(event, post._id)}
                                type="button"
                                className="btn btn-light mr-1">
                                <i
                                    className={classnames('fas fa-thumbs-up', {
                                        'text-info': findUserLike(post.likes)
                                    })}
                                />
                                <span className="badge badge-light">{post.likes.length}</span>
                            </button>
                            <button
                                onClick={(event) => onUnlikeClick(event, post._id)}
                                type="button"
                                className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                            >
                                <i className="text-secondary fas fa-thumbs-down" />
                            </button>
                            <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="btn btn-info mr-1">
                                Comments
                            </Link>
                            {post.user === auth.user.id ? (
                                <button
                                    onClick={(event) => onDeleteClick(event, post._id)}
                                    type="button"
                                    className="btn btn-danger mr-1"
                                >
                                    <i className="fas fa-times" />
                                </button>
                            ) : null}
                        </span>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

class PostItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onDeleteClick = this.onDeleteClick.bind(this);
        this.onLikeClick = this.onLikeClick.bind(this);
        this.onUnlikeClick = this.onUnlikeClick.bind(this);
        this.findUserLike = this.findUserLike.bind(this);
    }
    onDeleteClick(event, id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.deletePost(id);
    }

    onLikeClick(event, id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.addLike(id);
    }

    onUnlikeClick(event, id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.removeLike(id);
    }

    findUserLike(likes) {
        const { auth } = this.props;
        if (likes.filter(like => like.user === auth.user.id).length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { post, auth, showActions } = this.props;
        return (
            <PostItemComponent
                post={post}
                auth={auth}
                showActions={showActions}
                onDeleteClick={this.onDeleteClick}
                onLikeClick={this.onLikeClick}
                onUnlikeClick={this.onUnlikeClick}
            />
        );
    }
}

PostItem.defaultProps = {
    showActions: true,
};

PostItem.propTypes = {
    deletePost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    addLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    removeLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deletePost, addLike, removeLike })(PostItem);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! So basically you are nesting the presentational component in the container component and passing down props. Is this the best practice in how to work with this? In the documentation (https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) I see a different approach with connect and mapDispatchToProps. How does this exactly work?

Comment: Yes, that is my solution, this way you can manage different logic in appropriate way.

Comment: I have been changing all my components in the format you suggested and works perfectly. Thanks a lot! Is there a reason to use prop-types only in the container component? According to this article (https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) prop-types are validated in the component, so the component can "fail" loudly if something is wrong. How does this exactly work and should I use prop-types in the container only or both files?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar suggestion to @jsDevia's answer but I don't create a separate component here since you said your `Post` component is already connected to Redux. So, you can grab all action creators and state there and pass those to your `PostItem` component.

The second difference is I use a functional component instead of class component since you don't need any state or lifecycle method here.

The third difference is a small one. I removed all binding from your `onClick` handlers. For the `this` scope issue, I'm using arrow functions for the handlers. Again, we don't need any argument, like `post._id` to pass those function because we already have `post` as a prop here. This is the beauty of separating our components.

Using `bind` or an arrow function in callback handlers cause some performance issues for larger apps which have so many components like `Post`. Since those functions recreated every time this component renders. But, using the function reference prevents this.

```
const PostItem = ({
  post,
  deletePost,
  addLike,
  removeLike,
  auth,
  showActions,
}) => {

  const onDeleteClick = () => deletePost(post._id);
  const onLikeClick = () => addLike(post._id);
  const onUnlikeClick = () => removeLike(post._id);
  const findUserLike = likes => {
    if (likes.filter(like => like.user === auth.user.id).length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="card card-body mb-3">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-2">
          <a href="profile.html">
            <img
              className="rounded-circle d-none d-md-block"
              src={post.avatar}
              alt=""
            />
          </a>
          <br />
          <p className="text-center">{post.name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-10">
          <p className="lead">{post.text}</p>
          {showActions ? (
            <span>
              <button
                onClick={onLikeClick}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-light mr-1"
              >
                <i
                  className={classnames("fas fa-thumbs-up", {
                    "text-info": findUserLike(post.likes),
                  })}
                />
                <span className="badge badge-light">{post.likes.length}</span>
              </button>
              <button
                onClick={onUnlikeClick}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-light mr-1"
              >
                <i className="text-secondary fas fa-thumbs-down" />
              </button>
              <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="btn btn-info mr-1">
                Comments
              </Link>
              {post.user === auth.user.id ? (
                <button
                  onClick={onDeleteClick}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-danger mr-1"
                >
                  <i className="fas fa-times" />
                </button>
              ) : null}
            </span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

By the way, do not struggle with the example that is given on Redux's documentation. I think it is a little bit complex for newcomers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes it even cleaner! Also I've read using event handler written as arrow functions still falls under experimental syntax (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). Does this affect performance? It does prevent the need of function binding and therefore can be written as a functional component without a constructor. I wonder if it's a tradeoff or actually safe to use.

Comment: Arrow functions are slightly slower than the regular ones when they transpiled. But I don't think this difference is a big deal. By the way, class or functional separation is not like that. If you don't need a state or any lifecycle method you can use and should use a functional component. We don't use class components because we have to bind our functions. This is not the reason :) We use class components since we need a state or lifecycle method, we bind our functions in this components since we need to use `this` in callbacks. Functional components are free from these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Yes, aside from more readable code, making it stateless was for me one of the reasons for wanting to use functional components. This is so I don’t accidentally change states when I don’t have too.